# query multiple each statement keeping variabled at one level

Tags: jquery, push, each

I am trying to get to the bottom of the best way of doing something in Jquery.

HTML

```
<div class="questionblock" id="questionblock1" data-load="questionblock2">
                    <div class="row inline">
                        <div class="labelholder">
                            <strong>Q:</strong>
                            <label>Question 1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputholder">
                            <strong>A:</strong>
                            <select data-val="question1">
                                <option data-value="default">Please select</option>
                                <option>Answer 1</option>
                                <option>Answer 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="questionblock" id="questionblock2" data-load="questionblock3">
                    <div class="row inline">
                        <div class="labelholder">
                            <strong>Q:</strong>
                            <label>Question 2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputholder">
                            <strong>A:</strong>
                            <select data-val="question1">
                                <option data-value="default">Please select</option>
                                <option>Answer 1</option>
                                <option>Answer 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row inline">
                        <div class="labelholder">
                            <strong>Q:</strong>
                            <label>Question 3</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inputholder">
                            <strong>A:</strong>
                            <select data-val="question2">
                                <option data-value="default">Please select</option>
                                <option>Answer 1</option>
                                <option>Answer 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#content').removeClass('nojs');
                $('.questionblock').not('#questionblock1').hide();
                $('.questionblock').each(function () {
                    var myQuestions = [];
                    var block = $(this).attr('id');
                    var load = $(this).data('load');            
                    $(this).children().children().children('select').each(function () {
                        var questions = $(this).data('val');
                    });
                    console.log(block, questions);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I want to be able to get each div with a class of questionblock, read the id, then get all the select boxes within this div, and output their data-val so I can validate it all at one level.

http://jsfiddle.net/VEtx8/

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var questions;
        function getQuestions() {
            questions = [];
            $('.questionblock').each(function () {
                var block = $(this).attr('id');
                var load = $(this).data('load'); // Not used?       
                $(this).find('select').each(function () {
                   questions.push($(this).data('val'));
                });
                console.log(block, questions);
            });
         }
         $(function() {
             getQuestions();
             $(".questionblock select").change(getQuestions);
         });
```

Comment: Is there a way of using push through 2 levels? http://jsfiddle.net/VEtx8/1/ or is there a better way of doing this? I need to update the array once the select has been changed

Comment: You can make `questions` a global variable by declaring it outside the `$(function()...)`. Then you can reset it in your `.change()` handler.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that makes complete sense, but how would I reset it within the change function? thanks again

Comment: Empty the array with `questions = [];`. Put the code in the answer into a named function, so you can call it during the ready handler and the change handler.

Comment: super star, I really need to get my head around functions properly, thanks again :)